# User Specific DLL for UWP

Tags: c#, dll, win-universal-app, file-handling

I am looking for a way to update a UWP Library for a specific user, the app is hooked into a server that I could easily send the new .dll file down with, can I just replace the file in the install folder like I could in WPF or a windows service?  Or could I have a second app that could do this when the original app isn't running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really dont think this is possible because UWP apps run in a sandbox.  You could not create a second app to update the first because it would not be able to access the files of the first app.